# How to verify SCIP compiled with Ipopt?

Tags: scip, julia-jump, ipopt

I am using SCIP via Julia (currently with SCIP.jl, previous with AmplNLWriter.jl). I compiled SCIP as follows per the instructions for SCIP.jl:

```
make SHARE=true GMP=false IPOPT=true READLINE=false ZLIB=false scipoptlib
```

I am able to call SCIP from Julia. I also confirmed SCIP works with `make test`. However, when I try to solve a (presumably non-convex) MINLP, I get the following warning message:

```
Quadratic constraint handler does not have LAPACK for eigenvalue computation. Will assume that matrices (with size > 2x2) are indefinite.
```

This message makes me suspect SCIP is actually not using IPOPT. How can I resolve this message and verify SCIP is, in fact, using IPOPT?

My model has many bilinear terms, some of which may lead to convex constraints. Thus I anticipate using IPOPT will accelerate SCIP.

Thanks, Alex

Comment: It should be SHARED=true.

Comment: The SCIP standalone binary prints a list of "external codes", which are libraries outside SCIP that it is using. If build with Ipopt, then it will print Ipopt in that list, too. I don't know if the SCIP/Julia interface is printing the external codes, but you might check the log.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to print this information: [SCIPprintExternalCodes()](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/group__PublicExternalCodeMethods.php#gaa7d584a114aa5e22c44266e9a6f2554a).